# How to define custom slot type for Device Name in Alexa Skill

Tags: alexa-skills-kit

I am building a skill for special controls of our devices. These controls are not available in Smart Home API. I need to set a custom slot type know as the DeviceName for my intent schema. But a DeviceName has really really a lot of possibilities. I can name a device cat light, Bobby's car, hamburger and etc... And I can't just write them all under the list of samples, it's just impractical.

Answer (score 0):

It isn't clear what you are asking. It sounds like you are trying to build an Alexa Smart Home skill, as opposed to a "custom skill".

Smart Home skills do not allow you to specify your own slots, intents, utterances, etc. You must use the smart home commands defined by Amazon.

If that doesn't work for you, then you'll need to create a custom skill. Then you can define intents, slots, etc.

Comment: Hi, to sum up my questions. I am asking about how to create a custom slot type for names. I know that I can write up to 50,000 values for a custom slot type. But I don't expect that I need to write all possible names for devices. As what I mentioned, I can name a device cat light, bobby's car, or whatever strange names. But how can I define such slot type which has a very wide range of possible values.

Comment: The sample values are just examples. I've seen other values passed in slots that were not specifically listed. I the rest of the utterance is enough to qualify the intent then you might get additional values passed also.
Your best bet of course is to find an AMAZON.* defined slot type though.

Comment: I see. If that's the case then why sometimes Alexa could not get the word properly? I have the word Romeo listed in my slot values list. But when I say "bedroom", I always get the word "Romeo", which really confuses me.

Comment: Have you tried using the build-in slot type AMAZON.Room?

Answer (score 0):

Amazon's [Recommendations for Custom Slot Type Values](https://developer.amazon.com/public/solutions/alexa/alexa-skills-kit/docs/ask-bp-sample-utterances#h3_custom_slot_values) state that your list of custom values do not need to contain all the values your skill expects. Amazon does recommend that you provide a representative set of custom values with representative word counts.

For example...

Let's say I have the following intent:

```
- Intent: MyFavoriteBand 
- Utterance: "My favorite band is {Band_Name}"
- Custom Slot Type: Band_Name
- Custom Slot Values for Band_Name
    * Ramones
    * The Pixies
    * The Grateful Dead
```

And the user says, "*My favorite band is The Cars*."

Your `MyFavoriteBand` intent would fire and the value of `Band_Name` would be "*The Cars*" even though that value wasn't included in the training set.

Comment: but when I test this on echo device its not capturing the exact value as "The Cars" rather capturing something weired everytime like "The caars", "theCars" etc. Any solution to that?